# Why doesn't chromium work on my Rpi3

Tags: chromium

My Raspberry Pi 3 cant install chromium... The terminal error looks like this:

```
Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only
available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  chromium-inspector chromium-bsu

E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate
```

Tried updating, still wont work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to install `chromium-browser`

Comment: I did. It won't load up.

Comment: Your question says no installation package. Launch it in terminal and see what it will say

Comment: this is what it says: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: undefined symbol: mmal_vc_init_fd

Comment: @NathanLerowsky How u fixed it can u tell me? I'm getting the same error

Comment: @RushikeshGomekar the installation candidate `chromium` is outdated. I fixed it by using `chromium-browser` instead. If this doesn't work on the first try, install an update and try again. (`sudo apt-get install update`)

Comment: ``chromium-browser`` doesn't work. results in the same ``mmal_vc_init_fd`` error mention in other comment